# Spring IDE installation error

Tags: eclipse

i am new to springs first i wanna install spring ide in my eclipse indigo,i already have install maven integration with eclipse,bt by installing spring ide through eclipse marketplace i am getting dependencies error.like this

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Spring IDE Security Extension (optional) 3.1.0.201210040510-RELEASE (org.springframework.ide.eclipse.security.feature.feature.group 3.1.0.201210040510-RELEASE)
  Missing requirement: Spring IDE Live Beans Graph 3.1.0.201210040510-RELEASE (org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.ui.livegraph 3.1.0.201210040510-RELEASE) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.zest.core [1.0.0,2.0.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Spring IDE Core (required) 3.1.0.201210040510-RELEASE (org.springframework.ide.eclipse.feature.feature.group 3.1.0.201210040510-RELEASE)
    To: org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.ui.livegraph [3.1.0.201210040510-RELEASE]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Spring IDE Security Extension (optional) 3.1.0.201210040510-RELEASE (org.springframework.ide.eclipse.security.feature.feature.group 3.1.0.201210040510-RELEASE)
    To: org.springframework.ide.eclipse.feature.feature.group 0.0.0
```

please give me solution,or any other alternative to start spring .Thanks in adv

Answer (score 4):

I also encounter this problem when install Spring plugin into eclipse under the Ubuntu platform. After I search the error by Google, there is a solution in [Spring forum](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?130953-cannot-install-Spring-Tool-Suite-%28STS%29-for-Eclipse-Juno-%283-8-4-2%29-3-1-0-RELEASE) for this error.

As them said, this error may caused by GEF not installed, because some of Spring features have a dependency with GEF, so you can install [GEF](http://www.eclipse.org/gef/updates/index.php) by Eclipse Update Manager. Please notice that there is a permission error when you install Spring plugin under Ubuntu, it may need write permission to install.

First answer, wish can give you some help. Thanks.